# MVC view filter one table with variable from another

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I have two tables I am trying to pull info from, one is the Job table where I have all the info for my jobs stored the other is a SavedJobs table where I hope to have the Id of a job correlate to the Id of the user who applied for it.

I want to display the list of Jobs a user has applied for by filtering the table in the view page with the Ids that are saved in the SavedJobs table.

Here is an example of a view that does not work because I don't know how to access the data of multiple models in a single view.

```
@model IEnumerable<JobPortalApplication.Models.Job>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Applicants</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Experience)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Education)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
if(item.ID.Equals(JobPortal.Models.SavedJob.JobId){//this does not work because I can't access JobId
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Experience)
        </td>
        <td>
            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Education)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
   }
}

</table>
```

I've also tried a method that allows multiple models in a single view like this but it didn't seem to work

```
//controller action
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    
    var Job1 = GetJobs();
    var SavedJobs1 = GetSavedJobs();

    IndexVM model = new IndexVM();
    model.JobsList = Job1;
    model.SavedJobList = SavedJobs1;

    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    User user = _dbContext.Users.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(model);


}

//view 

@foreach (var item1 in Model.JobsList)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.SavedJobList)
    {
        if (item.JobId.Equals(item1.ID))
        {
            <table class="table">
                <dt>
                    @item1.ID
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Type
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Location
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Company
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Experience
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Salary
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Education
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Date
                </dt>
                <dt>
                    @item1.Category
                </dt>
            </table>

        }
    }
}
```

If you can recommend a better way to saved jobs to a particular user I would be grateful for that too.

Comment: For the 2nd method you tried, with the IndexVM that has a property for JobsList and SavedJobList, you need to eleborate. You said "it didn't work", but never explained why. On Stack Overflow, you should always explain why, never just say "it didn't work". What happened when you tried it? Did the model populate correctly? When you attached a debugger and stepped through the code, did it flow through the code the way you anticipated? Did you get an error? Be specific about what you observed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter this data on the back side and only display it on the front side.

I guess you want the Job Lists that are on the Saved Job List

This can be addressed using the following LINQ expression:

```
 var newJobList = savedJobs.Where(p => jobs.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.JobID));
```